# Correct Way to Use a Mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

What I would like to know about the code below, is: Are the use of try catch blocks around method calls good practice. What are the follies in the code below?

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/recursive_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <uint32_t tMilliSeconds>
class Timer {
private:
    static Timer *_instance;
    uint32_t mMilliSeconds;
    boost::mutex mListMutex;
    boost::thread mTimerThread;
    std::vector<boost::function<void()> > mHandlerList;

    Timer();
    Timer(const Timer &other);
    Timer &operator=(const Timer &other);
    void Run();

public:
    ~Timer();
    static boost::shared_ptr<Timer<tMilliSeconds> > Instance();
    void AddHandler(boost::function<void()> tmpBoostFunction);
};

template <uint32_t tMilliSeconds>
Timer<tMilliSeconds>::Timer() :
    mListMutex() {
    mMilliSeconds = tMilliSeconds;

    mTimerThread = boost::thread(
        boost::bind(&Timer<tMilliSeconds>::Run, this));
}

template <uint32_t tMilliSeconds>
Timer<tMilliSeconds>::~Timer()  {
    mListMutex.lock();
    try {
        mTimerThread.detach();
    } catch (...) {
        mListMutex.unlock();
    }
    mListMutex.unlock();
}

template <uint32_t tMilliSeconds>
boost::shared_ptr<Timer<tMilliSeconds> >
Timer<tMilliSeconds>::Instance() {
    if (!_instance) {
        _instance = new Timer<tMilliSeconds>();
    }
    return boost::shared_ptr<Timer<tMilliSeconds> >(_instance);
}

template <uint32_t tMilliSeconds>
void Timer<tMilliSeconds>::Run() {
    while(true) {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(
            boost::posix_time::milliseconds(mMilliSeconds));
        mListMutex.lock();
        for (std::vector<boost::function<void()> >::iterator vect_it =
            mHandlerList.begin(); vect_it != mHandlerList.end();
            ++vect_it) {
            try {
                (*vect_it)();
            } catch (...) {
                mListMutex.unlock();
            }
        }
        mListMutex.unlock();
    }
}

template <uint32_t tMilliSeconds>
void Timer<tMilliSeconds>::AddHandler(
    boost::function<void()> tmpBoostFunction) {

    mListMutex.lock();
    try {
        mHandlerList.push_back(tmpBoostFunction);
    } catch (...) {
        mListMutex.unlock();
    }
    mListMutex.unlock();
}
#endif // TIMER_H
```

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This is not a review it is an explicit question with code.

Comment: OK, then where does help on "other follies" go?  A separate answer that can never be accepted?  Oh well.  Your shared_ptr usage isn't right... creating a new shared_ptr from a plain pointer for each call means that each of your shared_ptr returns will not be actually shared.  Store `instance` as a shared_ptr instead.  I don't think `detach()` does what you think it does.  Presumably you want to exit the thread.  For that you'll want a termination condition (or interruption), and a `join()` in the destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using boost, I would look into using a mutex in conjuction with a `boost::scoped_lock`, so that when the `scoped_lock` object goes out of scope, the mutex is "automagically" unlocked via its destructor call.  You then won't need to worry about interleaving mutex unlocking with your `try` and `catch` blocks, since the unwinding of the stack via an exception will release the lock on the mutex via the `scoped_lock` object.

Comment: This "scoped mutex" is called an AutoMutex by some.  In Qt it is a QMutexLocker.

Comment: @Jason scoped mutex is causing my program to lock were as my implementation does not. What might be the cause of this?

Comment: If the problem is re-entrancy, then make sure to use a re-entrant type mutex with the `scoped_lock` object.  The scoped lock is separate from the mutex type, so this type of abstraction works well for those scenarios.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where one function that holds a lock would call another function that also wants a lock.  A scoped_lock implementation would do exactly the same thing as your code, except with correct operation on errors. Perhaps your scoped_lock usage isn't correct?

Answer (score 0):

No, your use of catch blocks is wrong.  If exceptions do occur, you are causing more unlocks then you should be.  If `lock()` is successful then call `unlock()` once and only once.  You should use a lock wrapper that manages the unlock for you, eg:

```
class mutex_lock
{
private:
    boost::mutex &mListMutex; 
public:
    mutex_lock(boost::mutex &aListMutex) : mListMutex(aListMutex) { mListMutex.lock(); }
    ~mutex_lock() { mListMutex.unlock(); }
};
```

Then you can do this:

```
template <uint32_t tMilliSeconds> 
Timer<tMilliSeconds>::~Timer()
{ 
    mutex_lock lock(mListMutex); 
    mTimerThread.detach(); 
} 

template <uint32_t tMilliSeconds> 
void Timer<tMilliSeconds>::Run()
{ 
    while(true) { 
        boost::this_thread::sleep(
            boost::posix_time::milliseconds(mMilliSeconds)); 
        mutex_lock lock(mListMutex); 
        for (std::vector<boost::function<void()> >::iterator vect_it = mHandlerList.begin(); vect_it != mHandlerList.end(); ++vect_it) { 
            (*vect_it)(); 
        } 
    } 
} 

template <uint32_t tMilliSeconds> 
void Timer<tMilliSeconds>::AddHandler( 
    boost::function<void()> tmpBoostFunction)
{ 
    mutex_lock lock(mListMutex); 
    mHandlerList.push_back(tmpBoostFunction); 
}
```

**Update:** boost has its own `scoped_lock` class for this exact same purpose:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>

template <uint32_t tMilliSeconds> 
Timer<tMilliSeconds>::~Timer()
{ 
    boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mListMutex); 
    mTimerThread.detach(); 
} 

template <uint32_t tMilliSeconds> 
void Timer<tMilliSeconds>::Run()
{ 
    while(true) { 
        boost::this_thread::sleep(
            boost::posix_time::milliseconds(mMilliSeconds)); 
        boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mListMutex); 
        for (std::vector<boost::function<void()> >::iterator vect_it = mHandlerList.begin(); vect_it != mHandlerList.end(); ++vect_it) { 
            (*vect_it)(); 
        } 
    } 
} 

template <uint32_t tMilliSeconds> 
void Timer<tMilliSeconds>::AddHandler( 
    boost::function<void()> tmpBoostFunction)
{ 
    boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mListMutex); 
    mHandlerList.push_back(tmpBoostFunction); 
}
```

Comment: The scoped_lock is leading to what I feared and that was a non-recursive mutex begin locked multiple times. My code does not lead to that.

Comment: You are not using a `boost::recursive_mutex` in the code you showed, even though you are including the `recursive_mutex.hpp` header file. I don't know the difference between `boost::mutex` and `boost::recursive_mutex`, but on Windows at least, `boost::mutex` maps to `CRITICAL_SECTION`, which can be locked recursively within the same thread context.